# How to view network traffic in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: networking, soap, visual-studio-2019

I need to view outbound soap requests made by my asmx web service. I understand there used to be a network tool in previous versions that would cater for this?

What's the process in doing this in VS 2019? This is a common operation I'd imagine millions of developers need to do.

I tried using fiddler, but it wasn't picking up the soap requests.